# Twitter fabric IOS signup

Tags: ios, twitter, sdk, twitter-fabric

I'm using Twitter fabric to build twitter login. I have signed up for it and installed the sdk into my app. I'm able to use it fine on my machine.

But when I pushed the code into git and my coworker pulled it, he was not able to build since he was directed to a webpage to signup for Fabric...

Why he need to signup since I have integrated the SDK into my source? If everyone use it need to sign up, how am I suppose to build my app with it?

What did I miss and how to resolve this?

Edit: I found the twitter Fabric app is started automatically when I build my project... How to disable that? I also found Fabric.framework/run is started everytime... How do I build without start it...

Thanks!
Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out what's going on...

Just go to build phase in project and delete run script...